# ubuntu 20.04 struck while updating

Tags: updates, 20.04

```
todo@2222:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for todo: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
todo@2222:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-20.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.4.0.31.36); however:
  Version of linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 on system is 5.4.0.29.34.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-20.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` works ?

Comment: You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-headers-5.4.0-31-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: thank for your help. I deleted my vm machine @b.duGaray